# How to find number of words in a String using Python sqlite3 package?

Tags: python, sqlite

I need to use the sqlite3 package in python to write a command to find the number of words in a string. I don't know of any command in SQL that lets me parse a string by whitespaces and count up the words so I was wondering if there is a way to do that through the sqlite3 package.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite does not have a built-in function to count words.

If you have the latest Python version, you can use a recursive common table expression;
assuming you have a table `MyTable(ID, String)`, the following SQL query would count the number of space characters in each `String` value (which can be assumed to be one less than the number of words):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE spaces(id, spaces, rest) AS (
    SELECT ID,
           0,
           String
    FROM MyTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id,
           spaces + (substr(rest, 1, 1) = ' '),
           substr(rest, 2)
    FROM spaces
    WHERE rest != ''
)
SELECT id,
       spaces
FROM spaces
WHERE rest = '';
```

It might be a better idea to count the words in Python.